# How to display RTF document with formulas at RichTextBoxt?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, richtextbox

I`m trying to load rtf document to RichTextBox such this:

```
private void LoadTextDocument(string fileName)
{
    Rtb.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    TextRange range;
    System.IO.FileStream fStream;
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        range = new TextRange(Rtb.Document.ContentStart, Rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        fStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        range.Load(fStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
        fStream.Close();
    }
}
```

But formulas contained at document higher than should be

[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: Please paste part of the rtf with the first line in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, .NET RTF box is not even nearly 100% compatible with RTF files created using OpenOffice, Word or other editor. So i am afraid this task is not even nearly as eas or even possible.
I spent days trying to find a solution to a different problem (replacing text in a more complex RTF that was created in Word) using RichTextBox.

In the end, i went with an RegEx solution and replacing text directly in the file without using RTB.